# How to find out Mule flow status

Tags: java, groovy, mule, mule-studio

I have a Mule flow that I'm starting by means of the following script:

```
muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('targetFlow').start()
```

However, I'd like the script to be executed only when the flow is stopped. Is there any way that I can check this in the script before doing the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this method to validate if the flow is started. I hope help you.

```
AbstractFlowConstruct f = (AbstractFlowConstruct) muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("flowName");        
    if (f.isStopped()){
        // start flow
    }
// it can also be used : f.isStarted()
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternately you can use **Groovy** component to check the status and put your simple script as follows :-

```
 <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
                <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
            if(muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('yourFlowName').isStopped())
                 {
                  muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('yourFlowName').start();

                 }
           return message.payload;
                 ]]>
              </scripting:script>
     </scripting:component>
```

Note Groovy script is the easiest way to achieve this